# ffmpeg produces video with misaligned frames

Tags: c#, wpf, video, ffmpeg

I have a WPF app that uses DeckLinkAPI to stream video from Blackmagic capture card (similar to their 'CapturePreviewCSharp' sample project, which can be found here: https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/developer/)

'VideoInputFrameArrived' method is called when a video input frame arrives:

```
void IDeckLinkInputCallback.VideoInputFrameArrived(IDeckLinkVideoInputFrame videoFrame, IDeckLinkAudioInputPacket audioPacket)
{
    if (videoFrame != null)
    {
        CurrentFrame = videoFrame;
        VideoFrameArrived?.Invoke(this, new DeckLinkDeviceInputVideoFrameEventArgs(videoFrame));
        GC.AddMemoryPressure(videoFrame.GetRowBytes() * videoFrame.GetHeight());
    }
}
```

I want to record the stream to a file. So I open a ffmpeg process with these arguments:

```
// My source is 1080p
string args = $".\\ffmpeg.exe -y -f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgra -s 1920x1080 -r 30 -i - -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 23 \"{outputFilePath}\"";
```

And I write to ffmpeg's pipe:

```
// ffmpegInputStream = FfmpegProcess.StandardInput.BaseStream
public void WriteVideoFrameToProcessStream(Stream ffmpegInputStream)
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (isRecording == true)
        {
            if (ffmpegInputStream != null)
            {
                // Convert the frame to BGRA32 format and convert the video frame to a byte array
                byte[] frameData = ConvertVideoFrameToByteArray(CurrentFrame);
                // Write the frame data to the ffmpeg input stream
                ffmpegInputStream.Write(frameData, 0, frameData.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the video file output has misaligned frames. The frame looks like it has been shifted to the left. 1/5 of the frame on the right is supposed to be on the left.
[image]

I tried saving the `frameData` byte array in `WriteVideoFrameToProcessStream` to an image file and it looks fine. What could be wrong here?

Comment: Is your `frameData` length equal to `4 x Width x Height` for sure? What happens if you remove extras like `-preset ultrafast` to see if only basic encoding works? A quick trick you can try (if your compiler doesn't complain) is to **specify a second output** and check if the picture is fixed within that second file... `-crf 23 \"{outputFilePath1}\" \"{outputFilePath2}\"";`

Comment: @VC.One, thank you for the suggestion. I'm pretty sure the length of `frameData` is `4 * Width * Height`. I use ImageSharp library to load the image from `frameData` and save it to file, and the image looks fine. When I omit some options from the output part of `ffmpeg` coimmand, leaving `-crf 23` left, the video comes out as black and only 512KB for 1 minute of recording for some reason.

Comment: I wanted you to confirm that `frameData.length` is **82944008** bytes. This confirms you have enough bytes to make 1920x1080 image without pixel offsets or bad colours etc. Secondly are you able to provide a testable frame _"from Blackmagic capture card"_? It'll be faster than testing guesses about the next steps. **(2)** Don't omit options just remove the `-preset ultrafast` (in case it does something funky like dropping bytes to meet the "**ultrafast**" requirement, I doubt it but I've only got a censored and Gaussian blurred picture of black/white areas to use as reference about problem).

Comment: PS: Try as `string args = $".\\ffmpeg.exe -y -f rawvideo -pix_fmt bgra -s 1920x1080 -r 30 -i - -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -crf 23 \"{outputFilePath1}\" \"{outputFilePath2}\"";` then check if the **outputFilePath2** gave a correct picture in the output. I have FFmpeg (CLI) so if still not working please provide some testable bytes of **frameData**. I can just replace your `- i` with a file of your frame data and start checking for a solution (after recreating the problem in output).